# Displayport + VGA dual monitor in Redhat 6.2

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, redhat-enterprise-linux, displayport

I just got a new computer at work that only has a single DIsplay Port and a single VGA.

I can get the dual monitors in Redhat 6.2 to detect both monitors - but they both display the same thing, and I can't figure out how to make it just extend the desktop.

Where do I set this?

Answer (score 1):

On Red Hat, go to `Main Menu` -> `System Settings` -> `Display`.

If you want to enable the 2nd monitor, check the box next to `Use Dual Head` (depending on the version of Red Hat/Linux, there might be a separate tab in the `Display` dialog window for Dual Head graphics options).  To change the 2nd monitor's settings, click `Configure`.

According to this article, [Configuring the system for the second monitor on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 and Fedora Core 4](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/014dec05/features/multihead/), you can enable both monitors to use an "extended desktop" by:

> ...set the
>   Desktop layout option to Spanning Desktops. To create a pair of
>   independent workspaces, set the Desktop layout option to Individual
>   Desktops. With "spanned desktops" you can drag windows from one
>   monitor to another; with individual desktops only the mouse cursor can
>   move between desktops.

Note that you have to save your settings and *then log out and back in (or reboot) your computer in order to see the changes*, they won't happen right away.

Comment: I thought I would see this - however, my Display system settings does not have any tab or options for using Dual Head

Comment: @Derek then I'm pretty sure your graphics card *doesn't* support it. I know a lot of PCs will support showing the same screen on multiple displays, but not extended desktops. My older laptop is like that.

Comment: Updated my distro to redhat 6.1 and it worked out of the box. Weird